# Constructor can't infer template argument from concept

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++20, c++-concepts

Why constructor can't infer template argument from concept in this situation? Also maybe there is a way to not specify concrete template type in serializer concept.

```
#include <span>

template <class impl_t>
concept stream = requires(impl_t &impl) {
  { impl.write(std::span<const std::byte>{}) };
};

struct any_t {};
template <class impl_t, class stream_t>
concept serializer = requires(impl_t &impl, const stream_t &stream, any_t &any) {
  ::stream<stream_t>;
  { impl.serialize(any) } -> std::same_as<stream_t>;
};

class memory_stream {
public:
  void write(std::span<const std::byte> data) noexcept {
    
  }
};

template <stream stream_t>
class json_serializer {
public:
  template <typename T>
  stream_t serialize(const T &value) {
    return {};
  }
};

template <stream stream_t, serializer<stream_t> serializer_t>
class client {
public:
  explicit client(serializer_t &serializer) noexcept {
    
  }
};

int main() {
  json_serializer<memory_stream> s;
  client c(s);
}
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/53qc9e)

Comment: I don't think concept has anything to do with deduction?

Comment: Is there a way to do it?

Comment: what about `template <stream stream_t, template <typename> typename S>
requires serializer<S<stream_t>,stream_t>
class client{explicit client(S<stream_t> &serializer);}`?

Comment: wow, didn't think about it, I thought that concept is already template of template in this case, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just not the way deduction works in C++20.

For class template argument deduction (CTAD), the `client` class template needs to deduce two types (`stream_t` and `serializer_t`) and the constructor you have only uses one of those types, so the language has no idea where the other one could come from.

You can help this by providing a deduction guide for `json_serializer`:

```cpp
template <stream S>
client(json_serializer<S>) -> client<S, json_serializer<S>>;
```

And now `client c(s);` works because you're telling it where the stream type comes from in this context. This could be generalized to any kind of serializer if you add some associated type for *what* stream a serializer is associated with.

As a guess:

```cpp
template <typename S>
using stream_for = decltype(std::declval<S&>().serialize(42));

template <typename Serializer>
client(Serializer) -> client<stream_for<Serializer>, Serializer>;
```

Which would help if there was a unary concept for `serializer` rather than a binary one.

---

Note that in your concept definition, the requirement:

```cpp
::stream<stream_t>;
```

Does not check that `stream_t` satisfies the `stream` concept. It checks that this is a valid expression. Which it would be regardless of whether the concept is satisfied or not (`false` is just as much a valid expression as `true`).

This needs to be:

```cpp
requires ::stream<stream_t>;
```

Or, even better:

```cpp
template <class Serializer, class Stream>
concept serializer_for =
    stream<Stream>
    && requires (Serializer& s, any_t a) {
           { s.serialize(a) } -> std::same_as<Stream>;
       };
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, it helps me with understanding argument deduction, but I have a question.  Can it work with serializers that depends not only on stream_t template type, but for example on stream_t template type + zero/one/two/three more? In generic way

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo Sure, nothing here depends on what the shape of the serializer type looks like. You can have a type that satisfies `serializer_for<memory_stream>` that isn't even a class template.

Comment: cause it looks like a hack :D

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo Yeah. You can make the serializer mandate that it provides a stream_type explicitly if you prefer that: https://godbolt.org/z/T6e88v.

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo This `implt_t` thing you're doing is a pretty bad naming convention, I would suggest not doing that. Both because `impl_t` and `impl` are look almost identical and mean different things, and also because `impl_t` doesn't mean anything while also being longer and less familiar than the usual metasyntactic type variable for templates, which is `T`.

Comment: Okay, thank you, will rename in my codebase

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the class as

```
template <stream stream_t, template <typename> typename S> 
requires serializer<S<stream_t>,stream_t> 
class client{
   explicit client(S<stream_t> &serializer){}
}
```

or you can add deduction guide

```
template<typename Stream, template<typename> typename Serializer>
client(Serializer<Stream>) -> client<Stream,Serializer<Stream>>;
```

---

As also note by @Barry, you need to modify your constraint definition.
For example:

```
template <class T>
concept stream = requires(T &t) {
  { t.write(std::span<const std::byte>{}) };
};

struct any_t {};
template <class T, class S>
concept serializer = stream<S> && requires(T t, any_t &any) {
  { t.serialize(any) } -> std::same_as<S>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the same question for this solution :) Can it work with serializers that depends not only on stream_t template type, but for example on stream_t template type + zero/one/two/three more? In generic way

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo can you give an example?

Comment: @VladyslavMozhvylo you need some way to extract the correct `stream` parameter, One simple way is adding it as member type definition (and get it like `S::stream_type`).

Comment: Doing `template <typename> typename S` is not a good solution here - it mandates that the only allowed serializer type is a class template that has a single template parameter that is the stream. That's extremely specific, and disallows serializers that might not be templates or might be templates but whose template parameter has nothing to do with the stream.

Comment: @Barry From [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373284/constructor-cant-infer-template-argument-from-concept/66374166?noredirect=1#comment117342703_66373284), 
it do represent a template template in OP's sense.
Of course it can just be any type, as I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66373284/constructor-cant-infer-template-argument-from-concept/66374166?noredirect=1#comment117343809_66374166), 
you only need to find way to get the stream type.